# Office365 - Application authentication with no user consent

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, office365

We've been working with EWS Managed services for a while now, however we would like to transition over to using the RESTful API for Office 365.

Is it possible for an application to access all of our users data without their consent? We have an in-house application that we would like to get some O365/Sharepoint data to our users. Using SSO isn't really an option, as we don't want to keep asking our users to give consent (we assume they already give it). Specifically, we want access to calendars and mail.

Are these "service/application level" accounts available in O365 yet? I think I read a while ago that they are on the roadmap but I have not seen anything since.

Would it be best for us to continue using impersonation with EWS for now until it is ready? (For some reason, EWS is painfully slow when getting data, meanwhile our tests with O365 SSO are a great deal faster, but we do not want SSO).

Apologies if this does not meet the requirements for SA questions. Thanks.

**EDIT. Daemon and Service Apps are now possible with Office365. Check out this link.**

[Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 Mail, Calendar, and Contacts APIs (OAuth2 client credential flow)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App-level authentication is coming soon. Basically an organization administrator will have to consent to allow the application access to mailboxes in their organization, then you'll be able to authenticate as the app, rather than acting on individual users' behalf.

I'd say keep working on your prototype using the user consent model that's in place now, and keep an eye on our [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/) or my Twitter account (@JasonJohMSFT) for the announcement for app-level auth.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I'll keep an eye out. We're really eager to get using the new authentication :)

Comment: that is different paradigm though, admin will have to register the app first in it's tenant